# SQL get players who played for 3 consecutive years on team

Tags: mysql

I'm new to using MySQL and am stuck on a query I have to write. Given a database of baseball players in the MLB, and all their statistics, I need to write a query that will show which players played for at least 3 consecutive years on the Boston Red Sox baseball team. Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT player.nameFirst, player.nameLast
FROM player
WHERE (...something something...) >= 3
AND player.teamID = "Boston Red Sox"
```

As well as the player table, there is another table called appears, which contains the playerID, and then the year they played for a team. The appears table also has other information such as their stats for that season. For example if one player played for the red sox 4 years, we would see four rows in the appears table, each row with an integer indicating what year they played on that team.

I know that after where the query gets complicated, I'm not sure how I would first off, count the number of years the player has been on the team, let alone how to know if those years were consecutive or not. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not enough information... where is some date field?

Comment: Sorry about that, check my edits ^

Comment: Find players who weren't not on a team for 3 consecutive years.

Answer (score 4):

Join the `appears` table with itself twice to find appearances on related years.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.playerID
FROM appears AS a1
JOIN appears AS a2 ON a1.playerID = a2.playerID AND a1.year = a2.year-1
JOIN appears AS a3 ON a1.playerID = a3.playerID AND a1.year = a3.year-2
```

You can join this subquery with your original query to get other information regarding those players.

`DISTINCT` ensures that we only return the player ID once even if they've played for more than 3 consecutive years.

Comment: Hmm... when I try this query I get an error saying "Lost connection to MySQL server during query". Could it be that the query takes too long to compute? After all these tables I'm working with are very large.

Comment: If it's large, add an index on the `year` column.

Comment: @cheesebal35 verify the connection to MySQL with another simple query. Also verify the names of the fields are correct.

Comment: This is an unsatisfactory answer in my view. :-(

Comment: @cheesebal35 I left out matching the player ID between the rows. Oops!

Answer (score 1):

Following the @Barmar's instructions, your query should looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT player.nameFirst, player.nameLast
FROM player
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT a1.playerID
    FROM appears AS a1
    JOIN appears AS a2 ON a1.year = a2.year-1
    JOIN appears AS a3 ON a1.year = a3.year-2
) AS ap ON player.playerID = ap.playerID
WHERE player.teamID = "Boston Red Sox"
```

Comment: This query looks good, I think it's just taking too long on my machine to execute. Every time it fails after 30 seconds of running.

Comment: See the edit to my answer, I forgot to use player ID in the self-joins.